# Populating Listbox with Jquery calls onClick two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, listbox, onclick

I´m having this dropdownlistbox

```
<select name="ddlViewBy" id="ddlViewBy" style="width: 143px;">
        <option style="display:none" value="0">Add Song to Playlist</option>
        <?php foreach ($selothers as $rowsothers) {
            $addvideoname = $rowsothers['name'];
            $addvideoid = $rowsothers['id'];
            echo '<option value="'.$addvideoid.'">'.$addvideoname.'</option>';
        }
?> </select>
```

I also run a script that populates the < select > with new data when it is being clicked.

```
<script>
    $("select#ddlViewBy").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getndata.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
               $('#ddlViewBy').html(html);
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

The ajax call works fine and I receive the new data onClick.
Although when I choose an < option > it does the ajax call again and will therefore put the  first < option > as the selected item.

Comment: As a side note, never use tag names before id-selectors like you have here: `select#ddlViewBy`. Id's are unique so you should always use `#ddlViewBy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by extending the < select > with: onFocus="function()"

and putting the javascript in a function without the ".click"